Russell's acquittance and description

One   interesting result of the above theory of denoting is this: when there is anything with which we do not have immediate acquaintance, but only definition by denoting phrases, then the propositions in which this thing is introduced by means of a denoting phrase do not really contain this thing as a constituent, but contain instead the constituents expressed by the several words of the denoting phrase. Thus in every proposition that we can apprehend (i.e. not only in those whose truth or falsehood we can judge of, but in all that we can think about), all the constituents are really entities with which we have immediate acquaintance. Now such things as matter (in the sense in which matter occurs in physics) and the minds of other people are known to us only by denoting phrases, i.e. we are not acquainted with them, but we know them as what has such and such properties. Hence, although we can form propositional functions C (x) which must hold of such and such a material particle, or of So-and-so’s mind, yet we are not acquainted with the propositions which affirm these things that we know must be true, because we cannot apprehend the actual entities concerned. What we know is “So-and-so has a mind which has such and such properties” but we do not know “A has such and such properties,” where A is the mind in question. In such a case, we know the properties of a thing without having acquaintance with the thing itself, and without, consequently, knowing any single proposition of which the thing itself is a constituent.

It's from Russell's "On Denoting".
I don't understand the difference between “So-and-so has a mind which has such and such properties” and “A has such and such properties,” where A is the mind in question.
Isn't the first example implying some degree of knowing about so-and-so's mind? Can't we substitute A in the second example for "So-and-so's mind"?
If we can, then it's literally the same meaning as in the first case, no?

Humans are only directly acquainted with ready-to-hand tables and chairs not present-at-hand physical matter comprising and arranging them, in the same manner the perennial problem of other minds are usually inferred by analogy or best explanation indirectly, therefore you cannot simply substitute using the law of identity of indiscernibles...

To know “A has such and such properties” we need to know both sides of the sentence. But we cannot know A because it can only be known by acquaintance. This is analogous to not knowing that "this has such and such properties" without seeing "this" that someone is pointing at. But when A or "this" is replaced by description, e.g. as so-and-so's mind defined as a peculiar entity or activity attached to so-and-so, then we can know that the thing so described has such and such properties. We cannot substitute the description for A itself because they have different intensions.
